# Query two tables with mysql to count total topics by hour

Tags: mysql

my forum have two tables to store topics (posts and forums_archive_posts)

```
$this->DB->build( array(
                                    'select'    => "HOUR( FROM_UNIXTIME( post_date ) ) as hour, COUNT(*) AS postCount",
                                    'from'      => 'posts',
                                    'where'     => "new_topic=0 AND author_id=" . $member['member_id'],
                                    'group'     => 'HOUR( FROM_UNIXTIME( post_date ) )',
                        )       );
```

This query works only with the first table (posts), I need a query that works also in "forum_archive_posts"

**tables structure** (forum_archive_posts=posts):

archive_author_id = author_id

archive_content_date = post_date

Comment: normal query format is: `select HOUR( FROM_UNIXTIME( post_date ) ) as hour, COUNT(*) AS postCount from 'posts' where new_topic=0 AND author_id='x' Group by HOUR( FROM_UNIXTIME( post_date ) )`

Answer (score 0):

No idea of how you do it in that format but something like

```
Select postHour, sum(postcount) as postCount From
(
  select Hour ...  as PostHour
  From 
  Posts...
  Union
  Select Hour ...
  From
  ForumArchivePosts ...
) dummyTableName
Group by PostHour
```

should do the job. the do count bny hoiurs from both tables, then add them together.